# Can't mount HDD /wrong fs type, bad superblock

Tags: 13.10, mount, hard-drive, ext4, devices

When I try to mount my HDD using:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdd /media/jinglez/MainFiles
```

I get this error:

```
jinglez@jinglezServer:~$ mount /dev/sdd /media/jinglez/MainFiles
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

As requested, I ran `dmesg | tail` which returned:

```
jinglez@jinglezServer:~$ dmesg | tail
[   64.337321] init: transmission-daemon main process (882) terminated with status 127
[   64.337361] init: transmission-daemon respawning too fast, stopped
[   64.896160] tg3 0000:02:00.0: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[   65.695028] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   65.695463] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   99.933921] systemd-hostnamed[3202]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[  120.906364] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (4631) terminated with status 1
[  377.372510] EXT4-fs (sdd): bad geometry: block count 732566646 exceeds size of device (732566381 blocks)
[  380.264264] EXT2-fs (sdd): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
[  382.129108] EXT3-fs (sdd): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
```

Answer (score 2):

After vigorous research on something I really know nothing about, I did find my solution.

After 'googling' pretty much every line that looked like an error in the dmesg, the bad geometry block was my winner.

`377.372510] EXT4-fs (sdd): bad geometry: block count 732566646 exceeds size of device (732566381 blocks)`

Have a block count that exceeds the size of the device blocks makes sense. However I was very scared when reading that I should use `resize2fs` to resize it, I took a deep breath, and wallah! I was able to view my files again.

I knew that I only had about 1.5TB of space used on the disk, so just to be safe, I did this:

`resize2fs /dev/sdd 2500000M`

I was then able to mount the drive without any problems!

That was my solution!

Comment: For your information: you can (and in fact should) accept your own answer when you find the solution to your problem yourself. It helps others with the same problem find the solution at a glance and also prevents the StackExchange system from periodically "poking" and highlighting it as an unanswered question.

Comment: I would have, but it doesn't let me do it for 2 days! :( @n.st